# PHP :What is the right approach for auto deleting a row on a database and saved data on server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hello guys I need an advice with these situation :

For example I have a free classified posting website where in a user can post classified ads..
The ad would be listed on the website for a maximum of 30 days then on 31st day it will automatically be deleted on the database as well as the images on the server.. The question is :

```
$db_ad_tbl('id','user_id','title','description',timestamp);
```

What is the right approach for doing this?
Can anyone suggest tutorials/links that covers this the same situation?

Comment: Use a cron job that deletes rows where `timestamp < now() - interval 30 day`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that does not require cron is to use MySQL events. If you can come up with the correct query, you can set it as a recurring event. phpMyAdmin 4.0.x supports events handling from the interface.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar has noted you should add a cronjob for this task. You can write a simple php script and then add it to your crontab with something like:

```
1 0 * * * php -f /path/to/file/clean.php
```

This means that the php file will be executed every day at midnight.

Just a few notes:

1. the file should not be in your web folder
2. you might want to do some tests and report errors by email(such as unable to connect to db)
3. If you build more of thees you should keep a list of them somewhere in case you switch servers(or the server dies)
4. if you use a config file(ex:to store your db connection details), you should make sure that it is accessible by the user that the cronjob works with.

Most hosting platforms allow for crontab editing and run them with the same user they run the web server so it should not be a problem.

There is really no other good solution to this then creating cron job. This is of course if you don't check the time stamp every time you get the data from the database.You can then delete it if it is bigger then the expiry data (DELETE FROM my_table WHERE timestamp>[Expiry Timestamp] ). This is of course risky, since you will have to include the timestamp every time you try a count, and risk storing everything forever if no expired resource is ever requested from the database.